# Bootstrap 3 Vs Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have been asked the following in an interview:

What was the problem in the grid system of bootstrap 3 which has been fixed in bootstrap 4, and I didn't find an answer that time and I searched a lot and never found a good answer but as I know that bootstrap 3 has col-sm, col-md, col-xl as per below:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when I was asked this question I got completely confused so please can someone help me to get the difference between them in details?

Comment: @לבנימלכה That only happens when you used `col-sm` three times, just to be clear. It detects automatically how many grid it will take, more [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns).

Comment: the OP talk about `col-sm`

Comment: @לבנימלכה It's just a sample code, OP is asking about the differences of the grid system in 3 and 4, and the fixes added to 4

Comment: I put all information in my answer (feel free to edit my answer)

Comment: [Read the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in bootstrap 3 you must set number after `sm` as `col-sm-3` if you do not set number it takes all row as `col-sm-12`

[see documention](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.3/docs/css/)

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm</div>
    <div class="col-sm" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-</div>
    <div class="col-sm" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In bootstrap 4 it become `4` if you use `col-sm`

[see documention](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

> Thanks to flexbox, grid columns without a specified width will
>   automatically layout as equal width columns. For example, four
>   instances of .col-sm will each automatically be `25%` wide from the
>   small breakpoint and up. See the [auto-layout columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns) section for more
>   examples.

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Bootstrap 4 grid VS boostarp 3**

*Bootstrap 4*

[image]

*Bootstrap 3*
[image]

Comment: so you mean that in bootstrap 4 the default is 4 and no nee to add number after col?

Comment: if you want `col-sm-4` yes you right you do not **must** to set `4` because it is automatclly

Comment: @Aly-Elgarhy Just to be clear, 4 is **not** the default size, it only happens to be 4 because you used three `col-sm`, which when divided to 12, gives you `col-sm-4`

Comment: yes it divided the col on 12 whatever you use without need to add numbers

Answer (score 1):

[**Grid system**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/#grid-system)

- Moved to flexbox.

  1. Added support for flexbox in the grid mixins and predefined classes.
  2. As part of flexbox, included support for vertical and horizontal alignment classes.
- Updated grid class names and a new grid tier.

  1. Added a new sm grid tier below 768px for more granular control. We now have xs, sm, md, lg, and xl. This also means every tier has been bumped up one level (so .col-md-6 in v3 is now .col-lg-6 in v4).
  2. xs grid classes have been modified to not require the infix to more accurately represent that they start applying styles at min-width: 0 and not a set pixel value. Instead of .col-xs-6, it’s now .col-6. All other grid tiers require the infix (e.g., sm).
- Updated grid sizes, mixins, and variables.

  1. Grid gutters now have a Sass map so you can specify specific gutter widths at each breakpoint.
  2. Updated grid mixins to utilize a make-col-ready prep mixin and a make-col to set the flex and max-width for individual column sizing.
  3. Changed grid system media query breakpoints and container widths to account for new grid tier and ensure columns are evenly divisible by 12 at their max width.
  4. Grid breakpoints and container widths are now handled via Sass maps ($grid-breakpoints and $container-max-widths) instead of a handful of separate variables. These replace the @screen-* variables entirely and allow you to fully customize the grid tiers.
  5. Media queries have also changed. Instead of repeating our media query declarations with the same value each time, we now have @include media-breakpoint-up/down/only. Now, instead of writing @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }, you can write @include media-breakpoint-up(sm) { ... }.

Comment: Yes, there were multiple problems that have been fixed. I'm not sure how an interview question can ask "What was the problem in the grid system of bootstrap 3 which has been fixed in bootstrap 4" and expect the interviewee to come up with the exact same problem the interviewer has in mind.