# Bootstrap CDN is not working when I use CDN instead of hosting remotely by using the downloaded .css file

Tags: html, css, cdn

CDN fails to load as the styles don't show when I view in the browser. Please look into it and let me know what the issue is as I am having a hard time debugging. I am almost giving up and about to become a celibate. PLEASE HELP!!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Project</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-4">Hello, world!</h1>
    <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
    <hr class="my-4">
    <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You cannot use bootstrap 4 classes in bootstrap 3. More info in the quick start on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: the document isn't helping me much understand the underlining concept behind my issue.

Comment: please describe a little closer what exactly is the problem. I amde your code runnable.

Comment: when i run the code(using CDN), all i get are the basic styles without the bootstrap. PS: Could you explain to me how two versions are different because all we do is take the written code and paste it in our document (unless we want to customize it ourself)

Comment: You took this sample https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/jumbotron/ from Bootstrap 4 but inserted the stylesheet from Bootstrap 3. There are many differences between BS3 and BS4. You only have to change this line `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">` That's all.

Comment: I changed it and tried it. Not working. The buttons show no bootstrap style

Comment: Differences between Bootstrap 3 and 4 is duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53757191/bootstrap-3-vs-bootstrap-4

Answer (score 1):

### If it is react or next js project, Instead of cdn file you can use below imports in your app.js file

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js";

### and do not forget to add

npm i bootstrap@5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

it works fine with the Bootstrap 4.1.3 stylesheet. It is better to add the 2 meta's in the head. Documentation on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any issue in loading CDN bootstrap file. It is working for me. Please check your browser settings.

Comment: What exactly in browser settings? Could you please specify it

Comment: The browser is not the issue here. Class "display-4" or other BS4 classes cannot be used with a BS3 stylesheet. Remove the BS3 stylesheet line and add the BS4 stylesheet line.

Comment: "<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Large button</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">Large button</button>". these lines should have worked then, but it is not

Comment: The classes "btn btn-primary btn-lg" works fine with BS3 and with BS4. But for example class="display-4" will **not** work in BS3.

Comment: Exactly, but the classes without the specifications whether it for 3 or 4 are failing to load bootstrap styles in my document.